# Updating ODBC database in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc

Is there any way to edit a single column of data within the database in ASP.NET c# using ODBC without having a unique id or sort to locate the exact column within the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: You mean *row*, right? Or do you actually mean column?

Comment: @SonerGönül Sorry bout that and thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @nvoigt It was a typing mistake I do mean row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No

If you want to pick a single row for updating, you will need a *key* to identify that row. Some databases offer their own methods of generating unique keys for rows, but still... you need that key.